# Java : Exception Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java

I have Problem while performing operation on Map I am digging to much not able to figure out  the following is stack trace...

> Stack Trace...

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.WeakHashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(WeakHashMap.java:806)
    at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:845)
    at java.util.WeakHashMap$EntryIterator.next(WeakHashMap.java:843)
    at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.forget(StyleManager.java:520)
    at javafx.scene.Parent.scenesChanged(Parent.java:652)
    at javafx.scene.Node.invalidatedScenes(Node.java:832)
    at javafx.scene.Node.setScenes(Node.java:898)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:495)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:221)
    at org.ArrayGen.FXFeatures.TitledPanes$6.run(TitledPanes.java:566)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$67/216599942.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$65/1943325854.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication$$Lambda$52/1136497418.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Use thread safe collections in place of HashMap ConcurrentHashMap etc

Comment: Share your code. It looks like you're modifying the structure of the map while any `iteration` is going on in it.

Comment: @user1354678 : i resolve error using synchronized block... now i am not getting the exception is it write way.....

Comment: @MohasinMujawar, It depends.. Unless u share the code, no one will know what is wrong..

Comment: @MohasinMujawar it is entirely possible for `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` to be thrown even in a single-threaded context. Please share a concise code snippet that reproduces the issue.